# Classifying the different types of fibers on $V(uX^2 + vYZ) \subset \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, fibration

I'm working on an exercise where I'm supposed to note the different types of fibers on $V(uX^2 + vYZ) \subset \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^2$. The way I was thinking to do this was to consider the following cases:

$X=0, Y = 0$

$X \neq 0, Y \neq 0$

one of $X=0$ or $Y=0$

and so on. I'm not really familiar with this kind of problem though. Is this the right approach?

On a side note, is this surface birational to something more familiar?

Comment: No point in $\mathbb P^2$ has $X=0, Y=0, Z=0$. In your other case you get one point, not two.

Comment: Sorry, it's late. You're correct of course.

Comment: Fibers for what map?

Answer (score 2):

You should consider the projection $$ p:V=V(uX^2 + vYZ) \to \mathbb{P}^2$$ All fibers have one point,  except those over $(0:1:0)$ and over $(0:0:1)$, which are copies of $\mathbb P^1$.
Hence $V$ is birational to $\mathbb{P}^2$.
 More precisely $V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^2$ blown up at these two exceptional points.

Comment: Fibers of birational maps are single points or connected (Zariski's main theorem), but how do you know the converse?

Comment: @ff90: the inverse of $p$ is also regular outside of the two exceptional points, since it is given by the formula $(X:Y:Z)\mapsto (YZ:-X^2)$. Hence   the restriction of $p$ to the complement of the blown up points is a regular  isomorphism onto the complement of the two exceptional points in $\mathbb P^2$.

Comment: \@Georges: Thanks for elucidating. I thought you were making the implication "fibers are singletons $\Longrightarrow$ map is birational" there for a second!